# Does a $G_\delta$ set of second category always contain an $F_\sigma$ set of second category?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, baire-category

We know that any $F_\sigma$ subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of second category always contains a $G_\delta$ set of second category, because an $F_\sigma$ set has the property of Baire and therefore can be written as the sum of a $G_\delta$ set and a
first category set. But does an $G_\delta$ set of second category always contain a $F_\sigma$ set of second category?

Comment: @HanulJeon But this perfect subset could be of first category, no?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made nonsense.

Comment: Hint: An $F_{\sigma}$ set of second category contains a closed set of second category...

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry I still don't see it. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Jiu If $X = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ is of second category, then at least one of the $X_n$ is of second category (a countable union of meager sets is meager). If it is closed then it is dense somewhere, so it contains an interval. But there are lots of $G_{\delta}$ dense sets that contain no intervals (e.g. the irrationals).